# Why do some apps have 'show in lock screen' and 'display pop-up windows while running in the background' permission default?

Tags: android, permissions

I am working on a alram app. My app code is working fine. I am testing my app API level 28 on MI phone Y3...I have a big problem that my app do not get some permissions like..

"Show on lock screen"
"Display pop-up windows while running in the background"

these are the permission that i have to allow the app manually in the phone setting, app permissions..... My question is that when i install the other Alarm app from the app store like "Simple Alarm", Alarm Clock, Alarm Clock Xtream...these app have the above mentioned permissions automatically... i mean i do not need to give these permissions to these apps manually.

Please help why these app have them default... If i give these permissions to my app manually... then my app works just fine... please tell why app app is not getting these permissions by default just like the other apps...

the activity that i want to launch has this code in onCreate before Super.onCreate....

{
 window = getWindow();

```
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=26){
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        PowerManager powerM = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, WAKELOCK_KEY);
        wakeLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);

    }else{
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        if (keyguardManager != null) {
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
        }
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        PowerManager powerM = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, WAKELOCK_KEY);
        wakeLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);
    }
}
```

Manifest permissions